# OverflowError: factorial() argument should not exceed 9223372036854775807

Tags: python

I tried the math.factorial() as

```
In [18]: math.factorial(10**20)                                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-88c39696b921> in <module>
----> 1 math.factorial(10**20)

OverflowError: factorial() argument should not exceed 9223372036854775807
```

I checked that:

```
In [19]: math.log2(9223372036854775807)                                                                           
Out[19]: 63.0
```

Why the limit is not set as 2^64, because it 8 bytes, 63 seems very odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a signed integer can be described on 64bits, but one of the bits is used for sign, so that's only 63bits left for the number itself (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Although Python integers can represent any signed number, there are limitations in some modules.

Comment: Not quite correct. Signed integers don't use one bit for the sign. They use two's complement.

Comment: That's a simplification, I agree, but it's still conveys the message. And you can consider the first bit as the sign.

Comment: I assume signed for one bit is very clear, could you please elaborate `two's complement`? @khelwood

Comment: Exactly, have a look, every negative value has the first bit set. That's the sign bit.

Comment: All negative number have that first bit set, but it could me misleading to say that is the sign bit, since changing that bit does not multiply the number by -1. but rather adds 2^63 to it.

Comment: Fair enough. I agree. Added the wikipedia link.